# Why date from date components does not return nil for wrong components?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I generate date:

```
private var date: Date? {
    let components = DateComponents(
        year: 2023,
        month: 2,
        day: 31,
        hour: 11,
        minute: 14
    )
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)
}
```

What is the output?

```
3 Mar 2023, 11:14
```

What to do to have nil returned when day components are out of expected number of days for selected month? Is there any parameter for this? Or should I calculate it manually?

Answer (score 1):

This question of “why” is difficult to answer. Apple didn’t document why. The old [*Date and Time Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW7) does in fact say that what you’re doing is undefined behavior:

> To guarantee correct behavior you must make sure that the components used make sense for the calendar. Specifying “out of bounds” components—such as a day value of -6 or February 30th in the Gregorian calendar—produce undefined behavior.

We could guess that it’s undefined behavior, rather than explicitly producing an error, because that simplifies the interface (it doesn’t need a way to return an error) and simplifies the implementation (no need to check for out-of-range values).

Digging deeper, it’s helpful to know that Foundation’s `Calendar` implementation, like all of Foundation’s locale support, is based on the [International Components for Unicode](https://icu.unicode.org/) library (ICU). You can find the relevant Foundation source code [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/f7d28f0df9f8170413b418ff76f61bf59e2d0415/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFCalendar.c#L1184). The ICU source code is [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu).

It turns out that the underlying ICU object, a C++ [`icu::Calendar`](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/main/icu4c/source/i18n/unicode/calendar.h), has [a “lenient” flag](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/classicu_1_1Calendar.html#a29c0974167c4d5b3570a87a55935224b), which is true by default, and which produces the behavior you’re seeing:

> With lenient interpretation, a date such as "February 942, 1996" will be treated as being equivalent to the 941st day after February 1, 1996. With strict interpretation, such dates will cause an error when computing time from the time field values representing the dates.

Foundation’s `Calendar` creates an `icu::Calendar` and never changes its lenient flag, so you get lenient behavior.

Why is lenient the default? I don’t know if that’s documented anywhere.

Comment: I think the "why" is easy. Is mentioned on the page [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate). Is because is a direct bridge from NSDate and NSDateComponents that doesn't care about the validity of the date neither in what calendar are you specifying this date.

Comment: If you could clarify where it says that `Date` or `DateComponents` “doesn’t care about the validity of the date”, I’d appreciate it. I couldn’t find any language like that on the page you linked.

Comment: literally on the first sentence after the title "Overview"... "NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone."

Comment: I don’t understand how independence from calendar and time zone has anything to do with the validity of a `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

This has struck me as strange before, and while I'm sure there is a logic behind it, rather than just basic maths, I've never worked out what it is.  My workaround is:

```
private var date: Date? {
    let components = DateComponents(
        year: 2023,
        month: 2,
        day: 31,
        hour: 11,
        minute: 14
    )
    guard components.isValidDate else {return nil}
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)
}
```

I feel like I shouldn't need to, but I've not found a practical solution to avoid it yet.

Comment: This is absolute valid, but I draw your attention to localization dates into different calendars if the isValidDate will work in those cases.

Comment: @AllanGarcia fair point, maybe I should have used the  `isValidDate(in calendar: Calendar)` variant, although in practice I've always been working with the user's current calendar (which may be my mistake!)

Comment: Yes, I was just to mention that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents/1780280-isvaliddate). Overall I tend to avoid use NSStuff bridge from Objective-C when you have another alternative... if not, ok. But If a modern structure is created on the API, is better to adopt as early as possible.

EDIT: As a final tip... I tend to create my own struct for dates wrapper style... using the Date under the hoods for better control and the most modern API as possible for my problem. Because I want to translate well for Hebrew and others calendars.

Comment: Also, check this statement: This method (func isValidDate) is not appropriate for use on DateComponents values which are specifying relative quantities of calendar components.
Except for some trivial cases (e.g., ‘seconds’ should be 0 - 59 in any calendar), this method is not necessarily cheap.
If the time zone property is set in the DateComponents, it is used.

Comment: @flanker I have a custom picker date for my watchOS app, and there is displayed 31 rows days (from 1-31) except columns for years and months. And I need to display selected date as `--` when selected day is out of range for selected month. Shortly, when date is nil, but is not;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe DateComponents is a direct bridge from NSDateComponents, and as stated in the oficial documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents)

> Important
>
> An NSDateComponents object is meaningless in itself; you need to know
> what calendar it is interpreted against, and you need to know whether
> the values are absolute values of the units, or quantities of the
> units.

Also another importante note in the same page is:

> Important
>
> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the
> DateComponents structure, which bridges to the NSDateComponents class.
> For more information about value types, see Working with Cocoa
> Frameworks in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4.1).

The better approach is to use the Struct **Date.ComponentsFormatStyle** [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/componentsformatstyle) using the property *fields* [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/componentsformatstyle/3766101-fields) to set the date components.